# How can i slide an image on canvas with mouse move?

Tags: html, reactjs, canvas, react-hooks

I am showing a part (300px*300px) of an image (1200px*1200px) with drawimage function of html5 in react. However i want the picture to slide in the canvas and show more of it when i move my mouse to the left/right sides of the canvas. So i wrote some code to do this like below

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRef,useEffect } from 'react';
import Space from "../img/space.jpg";
let canvas;
let ctx;
let ref;
let img_world;
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let pixels = 30;
let frames =1000/30;

function onMouseMove(e) {
    x = window.scrollX+e.clientX - (window.scrollX + canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    y = window.scrollY+e.clientY - (window.scrollY + canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    if(x<10 || x>290){
        moveCanvas();
    }
    pixels=30;
}
function moveCanvas(){
    if(pixels===350){
        return;
    }
    if(x<10){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        ctx.drawImage(img_world, 350-pixels, 250, 300, 300, 0, 0, 300, 300);
        console.log("to the left side: "+pixels);
    }else if(x>90){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        ctx.drawImage(img_world, 350+pixels, 250, 300, 300, 0, 0, 300, 300);
        console.log("to the right side: "+pixels);
    }
    pixels = pixels + 1;
    setTimeout(moveCanvas(), frames);
}

function World() {
    ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        img_world = new Image();
        img_world.src = Space;
        canvas = ref.current;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        img_world.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img_world, 350, 250, 300, 300, 0, 0, 300, 300);
        };
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);
        //canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", onMouse, false);
        return () => {
            canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        };
    },[]);

    return ( 
        <div className="screens">
        <canvas
            ref={ref}
            className="world" 
            width={300}
            height={300}
        />
        </div>
    );
  }
  export default World;
```

So as you can see from my code, when a mouse movement happens inside the canvas from left and right sides, it should trigger recursive mouseCanvas() function and it does then it supposed to drawimages 30 times a second until pixels variable reachs 350 but in browser i see only a movement happening once and not by 1 pixel. It seems like it is drawing the image once when pixels variable reach limit 350. What am i doing wrong here.

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript timeout in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115280/javascript-timeout-in-loop)

Comment: Try to look into `requestAnimationFrame` as using timeouts for this is very unoptimised and needlessly complicated.